# Excel Formula to merge 2 rows, except blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numbers in AZ (except some that are blank), and numbers in BB (except some that are blank). I'm trying to merge these together in BA to where if there's a number in AZ it'll take priority, if theres no number in AZ it'll copy the number from BB, unless they're both blank, then remain blank.

Nothing I've tried works.

I'm using 2013.

Comment: `=IF(AZ1<>"",AZ1,BB1)`?

Comment: @simoco close, but that puts a 0 in all the empty ones. I need the ones blank left blank (as this is 10k+ rows and would take forever to hunt those nasty guys down)

Comment: `=IF(AZ1<>"",AZ1,IF(BB1<>"",BB1,""))`

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a weird way of distinguishing between cells that are actually blank and cells that contain an empty string. Probably the only foolproof way to make a cell "actually blank" in Excel is to select the cell and press delete.

If your blank cells are actually blank, you can use this formula to merge AZ and BB (assuming you're on row 2):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AZ2),BB2,AZ2)
```

If your blank cells contain empty strings, you can use this formula.

```
=IF(AZ2="",BB2,AZ2)
```

And merging the two formulas so it supports both kinds of blank cells:

```
=IF(OR(AZ2="",ISBLANK(AZ2)),BB2,AZ2)
```

You can also compare to 0 instead of using `ISBLANK`, but I think `ISBLANK` is more readable.

Edit: to address your clarifying comment: there's no way for a formula in Excel to create an "actually blank" cell. The best you can do is return an empty string. Since you want this to result when both AZ and BB are blank, you need to nest an additional IF statement in your formula.

```
=IF(OR(AZ2="",ISBLANK(AZ2)),IF(OR(BB2="",ISBLANK(BB2)),"",BB2),AZ2)
```

Comment: Hmm this still leaves me with a 0 if the cell in BB is blank.

Comment: `LEN(TRIM(AZ2))=0` will test for blank, empty string and spaces only

Answer (score 0):

I have an example for 3 columns:

- A column has numbers but some cells are blank
- C column has numbers but some cells are blank
- B column verify:

  ```
  IF(A == [number]){
      B = A
  } ELSE IF (C == [number]) {
      B = C
  } ELSE {
      B = 'blank'
  }
  ```

Here are the Excel conditions:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1)=1,A1,IF(COUNTA(C1)=1, C1,"blank"))
```

Good Luck!